# JavaWebStart preventing JAXWS service call in WIN7 + Java6

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-web-start, connection-timeout

I have developed a JAXWS web service client app for desktop delivery via Java WebStart.  It works just fine under WinXP, both Java6&7, whether running under "java", or "javaws".
I moved to Win7.
On that platform, I consistently fail to connect to the service, when running JWS under Java6, whether under the browser or command line.
It just times out, as if it just could not make the http connection.  There is nothing showing up in the web log on the server side.
If I run it under regular "java" it works just fine.

Under Java7, it works fine, both "java" and JWS.

Using exact same jar in all circumstances, and have carefully checked that same soap address is always configured.

I've tried every thing I can think of, and at the moment, it just looks like a Java6 bug on Win7.
Has anyone else seen this?

The program was developed in NetBeans.
Clint

UPDATE
Problem solved.  Very strange behavior however.  There was a subtle java version incompatibility (the wsimport output was compiled with J7, inadvertently, but the rest with J6 as I intended).  The call made to the webservice blocked, as per usual, but never returned.  However, under the covers, an exception was thrown which killed the connection attempt.  The exception never percolated up the stack for some reason.  Seems like some layer down there misbehaved.  Anyway, I have fixed, although I'd still say there is a bug somewhere, probably in JAXWS code.

Comment: could it be a firewall issue with the failing jre? does wireshark detect any outgoing traffic? are you able to put traces in the code that attemppts to connect